# Recover from flag ban

Tags: support, flags, declined-flags

I get recently banned from flagging. But it's not quite clear to me why? In addition is there any way to recover from this ban? Will it age away and after 1-2 weeks it will be possible again?

I'm not quite sure what I'm able to do, to solve this?

This is my flag history:

```
36  moderator attention flags
5   waiting for review
20  deemed helpful
5   declined
4   disputed
```

I have 20 helpful and 5 declined. This is around 20%. Anyway, I don't get the point why some of the 5 were declined. Some posts were flagged to move them to another community or to close them as they are too broad/unclear. In fact, 3 of the 5 are closed/on hold or have a really low rating, but my flag was declined. And one which was mentioned to move to another community was also declined, but the answer is currently moved. So, why the hell I'm banned? Just because of some flag reviewer which really don't care about their reviews and quickly decide that flags are not helpful?

I just had 3 questions today which should be flagged due to off-topic and one because of spam (advertisement for a website). But yes, I can't flag them. Great job. This means that you just achieved that someone who was helpful for your community, just gets annoyed and won't help anymore.

I know there are some other posts like that, but not exactly on this case.

Hopefully someone can describe how to "unbann".

Comment: The link should explain how the system work; the issue with how your flags were handled is rather site-specific and does not belong here (which is a meta site for the network-wide issues).

Comment: Ah ok. This means I should post it on the meta page for the site where the ban occurs? I thought it would be globally the same. :-)

Comment: The ban applies per site, and the declined flags were declined by moderators of a particular site, based on the criteria designed for that site.